# Image not found in openssl.bundle，when install cocoapods on mac

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

when I try to install cocoapods on my mac, I installed ruby, as below:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

but when I typed command `sudo gem install cocoapods`, it shows the error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/openssl.bundle

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

$ ruby reinstall
ruby: No such file or directory -- reinstall (LoadError)
```

I am new to ruby, maybe it says missing openssl.bundle?

Comment: (esp. running `brew remove openssl; brew install openssl` should do the trick)

Comment: Wow, it works! the error has gone ，thanks! while install cocopods, there is a error`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String
` after `Successfully installed colored-1.2
Fetching: xcodeproj-1.2.0.gem (100%)`

Comment: try: brew upgrade ruby